# How to edit font type of UIDataPicker

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

In my iOS app I've implemented a UIDatePicker.
How can I edit the font?

Comment: You can't. There is no API to customize the look of a UIDatePicker`.

Comment: What is this API ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) says:

> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.

However UIDatePicker uses a custom subclass of UIPickerView so you can create your own date picker with a custom subclass of UIPickerView (a replica of the UIDatePicker) with the appearance you want. The function [view(forRow:forComponent:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614372-view) allow you to return a view for the picker view, you can use in that view a UILabel with the font you want.

Comment: No, UIDatePicker is not a subclass of UIPickerView.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are right, the Apple documentation says: "The UIDatePicker class uses a custom subclass of UIPickerView to display dates and times." So it is not a subclass from what I understand. I will fix this mistake, thanks!

Comment: Implementing your own date picker with UIPickerView is not trivial, especially if you want it to work properly with the user's locale.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a code of the UIPicker that I can take and the edit?

Comment: @JhonDoe you can maybe look at this Github project: https://github.com/HassanEskandari/HEDatePicker. It can help you or you can directly use it.